# Add an Id to ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to add an ID `(x:Uid="identifier")` to the last and first listbox item. My Listbox items are populated via data-source like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" 
     ItemsSource="{SomeBinding}">
```

Could it be done in xaml?

Comment: You can use `ItemsSource` binding source ID

Comment: sorry, I dont understand - Items Source is just a binding "mapping", and how is it possible to determine what exactly element of ItemsSource is the first or the last one?

Comment: `Listbox` will bind item in Item order only

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want to implement it, but here's some kinda of solution.

I figured you just need IDs of first and last items in your ListBox. Not sure you can do it in xaml without much work and headache.
You already have it binded to some object.
Let's say:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _Items;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return _Items; }
    set { _Items = value; }
}
```

So you could just get 'em like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var firstItem = Items[0];
    var lastItem = Items[Items.Count - 1];
}
```

Comment: yes, I think I could get them in ViewModel, but I dont think that this items have some Uid field.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from `ListBox` your custom class. Override protected method.. not quite remember which was the name... something about `.GetContainerFor(...)`. From there you might return `new ListBoxItem()` and set it up as you prefer.